# Android general navigation issues

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a general question about navigation especially when it comes to the action bar. The main issue I am having is that each time someone navigates away using the action bar it keeps that activity in the stack (unless I pass the intent flags to remove it). Is that standard procedure? Is it normal to have say 100 instances of one activity? If so, how are those activities garbage collected? Further, what is best practice if those activities contain images (ie: images are also kept in memory and duplicated)?

Comment: look at the launch modes for activity http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode. Images must be recycled. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html. FOr garbage collection check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081175/android-activity-garbage-collection

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about using the up button properly, you can use (or at least see) [`NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(Activity)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html#navigateUpFromSameTask%28android.app.Activity%29). It will set the right flags that won't duplicate the activity.