# Android Activity not garbage collected

Tags: java, android, android-studio, garbage-collection, memory-profiling

I am currently trying to understand the Android garbage collection and made a minimum (really minimum, see code below) example for testing. My test example is as follows:

1. `MainActivity`, which shows a Button "Show CountActivity"
2. `CountActivity` which is shown when the Button "Show CountActivity" in the `MainActivity` is pressed.
3. I end the `CountActivity` using my system back key

Using Memory Profiler I then initiate a garbage collection, then capture a heap. My expectation would have been to not find any `CountActivity` instance in the heap, but I find one. Can anyone please explain why? Screenshots of the Memory Profiler and the source code follows below.

[image]

[image]

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener {
      showCountActivity()
    }

  }

  private fun showCountActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(this, CountActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
  }

}
```

**CountActivity**

```
class CountActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_count)
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Activity Garbage Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081175/android-activity-garbage-collection)

Comment: Thank you, but except for also having only 2 activities, I couldn't find an explanation why the CountActivity in my example isn't garbage collected ): So, still looking for help in my example.